# como crear un array dinamico

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, reactjs

Tengo una constante "handleMonths" que tiene como valores un array el cual va cambiando de valor dependiendo de donde el usuario de click en un tree, handleMonth puede estar esta compuesta de la siguiente manera

```
[
 {id_month: 1453, name_month: 'Enero'},
 {id_month: 34636, name_month: 'Marzo'},
 {id_month: 7234, name_month: 'Julio'}
]
```

la cantidad de objetos que tiene dentro va variando según donde el usuario de click, ahora lo que quiero hacer es crear un array que tenga la siguiente estructura

```
[
  {text:"aqui el name_month" , value:"aqui el name_month", key:"aqui va el id_month" }
]
```

los valores de este nuevo array deben venir de handleMonths y al igual que este también seria variable, ¿como lo podria hacer?

Comment: Creo que usar `map()` es lo más prudente para lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Le hace falta informacion y codigo a tu pregunta. Como quieres implementar esto? Con hooks? o como?

Por si sirve de algo, con lo siguiente puedes mapear la informacion:

```
const handleMonths = [
  { id_month: 1453, name_month: 'Enero' },
  { id_month: 34636, name_month: 'Marzo' },
  { id_month: 7234, name_month: 'Julio' }
]

const newData = handleMonths.map((month) => {
  return {
    text: month.name_month,
    value: month.name_month,
    key: month.id_month
  }
});

console.log(newData);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias untilizar .map() es una funcion que dada un array puedes crear otra estrucutra con los datos del array que recorres.

```js
const newhandleMonths = handleMonths.map(month => {
   return {text: month.name_month, value: month.name_month, key: month.id_month }
});
```